# Ugly equations if a doc file is saved as a web page. What can be done?

Tags: microsoft-word, frontpage

I have tried to save, as web pages, doc files written in MS Word and containing equations. All formulas became quite ugly (see the image). I also copied documents in FrontPage, arranged them a bit and saved them with the intention to create a site. The result was the same, equations with an unpleasant look.

What can I do to improve the aspect of these formulas?

[image]

Comment: Use the snipping till tool to 'convert' it to an image. Makes updates impossible but if the formula won't change it may be OK as a work around

Comment: The equations are converted automatically to images when I save a doc file as a web page, each formula is a picture. I do not know how to instruct Word to save these images at a higher resolution or somehow with an improved look. I have many documents with hundreds of eq. I can not convert manually each of them in pictures. This is impractical.

Comment: Word and Frontpage are not really designed to create web sites.

Comment: How can you say that FrontPage is not designed to create web pages?! If you do not know the answer please do not write anything because you can mislead people that can help.